# Shell Script with conditional clauses for script output

Tags: oracle11g

I am new this site as well as new to shell scripting and this is my first form. Please help me with the following shell script.

I am executing a shell script to run every 15 min (scheduled in cronjob) and it gives an output in an output file which is e-mailed.

```
CONCCOUNT=`cat $OUT_DIR/EBS_Locked_Accounts.out|grep INVALID |wc -l`
echo $CONCCOUNT

if [ $CONCCOUNT != 0 ]
then
outputFile="$OUT_DIR/EBS_Locked_Accounts.out"
(
echo "From: oraiga@icp.com"
echo "To: $MAILLIST"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Subject: Locked Accounts in EBS"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
cat $outputFile
) | sendmail -t
```

My requirement is:

I don't want the script to send output every 15 min (cannot change the cronjob schedule) instead it should send the actual output every one hour unless there is a change in the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It you can't change the cronjob schedule, you can create a file that counts to 4 and then sends it and resets the count, since 15 minutes*4 = 1 hour. Like this:

`echo "1" > croncount.txt`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
CRONCNT=$(cat "croncount.txt")
if [ $CRONCNT == 4 ]; then
    if [ $CONCCOUNT != 0 ]; then 
    outputFile="$OUT_DIR/EBS_Locked_Accounts.out" ( echo "From: oraiga@icp.com" echo "To: $MAILLIST" echo "MIME-Version: 1.0" echo "Subject: Locked Accounts in EBS" echo "Content-Type: text/html" cat $outputFile ) | sendmail -t
    fi    
    echo "1" > croncount.txt
else
    CRONCNT=$((CRONCNT+1))
    echo "$CRONCNT" > croncount.txt
fi
```

Comment: The script now sends output to mail at the fourth execution, but I need to add one more condition that if there is any difference in the output between these execution, the script should the mail with the changes. Example: CONCCOUNT file has some value like 5 in the first execution (at 15 min), no change in value on 2nd execution, so no mail needed but now at third execution (at 45 min) the value changed to 6, then it should send the mail notification at 3rd execution itself. Hope I am clear in explaining my requirement. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're looking for, but if you want a compound statement, you can do something like: `if [ $CRONCNT == 4 ] && [ $CONCCOUNT != 0 ]; then`... 
Don't forget to vote up my answer if my answer helped

Comment: Thanks a lot... Unfortunately it is still not serving my purpose.